# Doctrine: How to fetch that query?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2 with PDO_MYSQL and I want to query that query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time), '%M %Y')
FROM Project\Posts
GROUP BY time
```

So I tried that:

```
    $q = $em->createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time), '%M %Y') FROM Project\Posts GROUP BY time");
    $r = $q->getResult();
    print_r($r);
```

But I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message '[Syntax Error] line 0, col 16: Error: Expected known function, got 'DATE_FORMAT''
```

So how could I query that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you should bypass ORM and work on DBAL layer, cause you're not doing any mapping.

```
$stmt = $dbal->execute('SQL (not DQL!) here');
$dates = $stmt->fetchAll();
```